# Poetry was not installed with the recommended installer. Cannot update automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-poetry

**How to I upgrade to the latest version?**

**Specification:**

- Windows 10,
- Visual Studio Code,
- Ubuntu Bash.

---

Current Version:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key/compositekey/tests$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

Attempt to update | `poetry self update`:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key/compositekey/tests$ poetry self update

  RuntimeError

  Poetry was not installed with the recommended installer. Cannot update automatically.

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/console/commands/self/update.py:389 in _check_recommended_installation
      385│         current = Path(__file__)
      386│         try:
      387│             current.relative_to(self.home)
      388│         except ValueError:
    → 389│             raise RuntimeError(
      390│                 "Poetry was not installed with the recommended installer. "
      391│                 "Cannot update automatically."
      392│             )
      393│
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Comment: Ah ok. I have a new error now. I've updated the post @Seon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message suggests you've probably installed `poetry` with pip, which does not support automatic `poetry` updates. You should uninstall the `poetry` version currently installed, and reinstall it using [the recommended method](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#installing-with-the-official-installer), which uses a custom installation script.

On osx/linux, you'll just have to run `curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -` to download and run this installation script.

Comment: I did install it using `pip`. How can I uninstall it? Ty

Comment: `pip uninstall poetry` seems to do it haha

Comment: `poetry self update` has the latest version. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As per [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69823066/9219425), it's quite likely that you've installed poetry with pip. But it you find `pip uninstall poetry` returns a warning saying that poetry is not installed, another possibility is that you've installed it with pipx.

Running `pipx list` will show you whether this is the case. You could then run `pipx upgrade poetry`, or you may want to uninstall it and just rely on poetry to manage its own installation/upgrade, as this seems to be fairly robust now.

*(I add this on the off chance that someone else, like me, had installed pipx for the specific purpose of managing their poetry installation and then completely forgotten about it, and finds their way to this question...!*  *)*

Answer (score 0):

**For mac users:** I was able to get it working by installing poetry with homebrew:

```bash
brew install poetry
```

**Note:**

- This is not the recommended way to install poetry: [Why is not recommended to install poetry with homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73365780/why-is-not-recommended-to-install-poetry-with-homebrew)
- [Best solution is to use `pyenv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75551642/10521959)