# Why is not recommended to install poetry with homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, python-poetry

Poetry official documentation [strictly recommends sticking with the official installer](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#installing-with-the-official-installer). However, [homebrew has poetry formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/poetry).

```
brew install poetry
```

Usually, I like to keep everything I can in homebrew to manage installations easily.

**What is the drawback and risks of installing poetry using homebrew instead of the recommended installation script?**

Comment: What specific words of the docs are you concerned about?  I don't see anything that would be a concern at all, they just say *"We provide a custom installer that will install Poetry in a new virtual environment to isolate it from the rest of your system. This ensures that dependencies will not be accidentally upgraded or uninstalled, and allows Poetry to manage its own environment."*

Comment: exactly this: "This ensures that dependencies will not be accidentally upgraded or uninstalled, and allows Poetry to manage its own environment." :)
feels like letting an external tool install it is not recommended for some reason

Comment: Is this a genuine concern, though? Folks who install using homebrew, have you had a `brew update` result in poetry going into a bad state?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The drawback is that `poetry` will be unable to upgrade itself (I've no idea what'd actually happen), and you'll not be able to install specific poetry versions. Homebrew installed poetry will probably also use the Homebrew-installed Python environment, etc, instead of having its own isolated `venv` to execute from.

If you use homebrew to install poetry, don't try to manage that installation any way outside of homebrew. Otherwise, it's probably fine.

Other misc drawbacks include:

- Can't control specific Python version used to run Poetry (want to get the latest core Python speedups!)
- Uncertain support and management of poetry plugins (part of "managing the installation")
- Can't run multiple poetry versions side-by-side

**edit**

My personal recommendation is to install `pipx` using homebrew, and then install `poetry` via `pipx`:

```bash
brew install pipx
pipx ensurepath
pipx install poetry  # latest version
pipx install poetry==1.2.2 --suffix=@1.2
pipx install poetry==1.3.2 --suffix=@1.3
pipx install poetry==1.6.1 --suffix=@1.6
```

so you'll get something like:

```bash
❯ pipx list
venvs are in /Users/redacted/.local/pipx/venvs
apps are exposed on your $PATH at /Users/redacted/Code/dotfiles/bin
   package hatch 1.7.0, installed using Python 3.11.5
    - hatch
   package poetry 1.2.2, installed using Python 3.11.5
    - poetry
   package poetry 1.3.2 (poetry@1.3), installed using Python 3.11.5
    - poetry@1.3
   package poetry 1.6.1 (poetry@1.6), installed using Python 3.11.5
    - poetry@1.6
❯ poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.2.2)
❯ poetry@1.3 --version
Poetry (version 1.3.2)
```

e.g. via:

```bash
brew install pipx
pipx ensurepath
pipx install poetry  # latest version
pipx install poetry==1.2.2 --suffix=@1.2
pipx install poetry==1.3.2 --suffix=@1.3
pipx install poetry==1.6.1 --suffix=@1.6
```

Poetry is still under very active development, and its API is not very stable. This gives me full control of what version to use/when, e.g. across different projects.

Answer (score 3):

On top of what Kache said, [homebrew poetry formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/poetry.rb) is actually built with the specific python version ([python@3.10](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/poetry.rb#L20)) in the virtualenv manner.

IMO, there are two reasons why there is poetry formula:

- it is required by other formula (like [dooit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/dooit.rb)) to do the build
- homebrew user would manage the tools in the consistent way (via [brew bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle))

Answer (score 2):

You can use Homebrew while sticking to officially recommended installation methods with one extra step.

- The pipx project officially supports Homebrew installation:

  ```
  brew install pipx
  pipx ensurepath
  ```
- `pipx` is an officially supported way of installing poetry:

  ```
  pipx install poetry
  ```